# BootStrap 3 container inside container-fluid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Below is the Layout that I am working on using BootStrap3. I have setup example with limited layout for this question at http://jsfiddle.net/s7Rwj/4

[image: WebSite Layout]

I am having hard time setting up my header. I am using container-fluid width so my Header's width is 100% however the ask is that out of three elements inside header one should stay to left and rest of the two should match left and right respectively of the below "container".

So far I have tried various layouts but below is the only one which is close to what I am looking for.

```
    <header class="container-fluid navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color:aliceblue">                    
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:violet">2</div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 pull-right" style="background-color: lightblue">3</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0">
                    A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

However challenge with this layout is that since the span is using absolute position when the browser is re-sized the text overlaps the second element inside header. I have already tried providing explicit width to it but it didn't help.

If I don't use absolute position then the span and rest of the items are rendered in two different lines.

I am looking for advice on how to setup this header.

PS: I have added random background colors to div tag to understand where they are getting rendered. Feel free to ignore them.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I think you're looking for difficulties where they are not.

You should avoid nesting containers (.container and .container-fluid) because they are not nestable due to their padding etc...  [look at Bootstrap 3 Containers overview](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container)

Also, when you are nesting columns, all you need to do is to put a new row into one of your columns and put the nested columns right into it. [See Bootstrap 3 Grid system - nesting columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting), here's their example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    Level 1: .col-sm-9
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
        Level 2: .col-xs-8 .col-sm-6
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6">
        Level 2: .col-xs-4 .col-sm-6
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The solution you're looking for with your layout is very simple. You don't necessarily need container-fluid in the header. Simply create a container for the center part above carousel and wrap it into a .wrap or any other class that you can style with width: 100%. Additionally, you can add some padding that container-fluid has.

```
<header class="wrap navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color: violet;">2</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 pull-right" style="background-color: lightblue;">3</div>
        </div>
        <span style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0">
            A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
        </span>
    </div>
</header>
```

And somewhere in your CSS (I recommend style.less), you can style .wrap to 100% width, though it should be default width for every div without styles.

```
.wrap {
    width: 100%;
}
```

I know this question is a lil bit older but it doesn't matter. Hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: This is not true for Bootstrap 4. According with documentation: "While containers can be nested, most layouts do not require a nested container…". So containers CAN be nested.

Comment: This is a topic about Bootstrap 3.

Comment: You should never have to nest a container inside anything. A column within a container serves as the container for any further nested rows/columns.

Answer (score 18):

I actually see no problem with using the Bootstrap container nested in the container-fluid. I did this recently in a theme I built that uses a page builder. This allowed the client to easily build pages with varying fixed and full width rows using the page builder.

Just add something like this to your stylesheet:

```
.container-fluid .container {
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
}
```

That said, I think what you are attempting may be solved by adding some padding-top to the first column in the container-fluid. To make it mobile specific, add that padding in a media query at the breakpoint where the text begins to overlap. That's not the prettiest way of doing it, but that's how I would approach it given what you are trying to accomplish.

```
<header class="container-fluid navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color:aliceblue; padding-top:30px;">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:violet">2</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color: lightblue">3</div>
                </div>
            </div> 
            <span style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0">
                        Some text
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

LINK: http://jsfiddle.net/udLbLwh6/

Comment: You should never nest container classes.

Comment: @TeeJay ... Aside from the padding issue (that's easily resolved in my solution), what is the harm in nesting containers? I have actually found it to be quite practical in layouts with varying fixed and full width content.

Comment: I disagree. Bootstrap, or any other framework for that matter, is simply a tool. Nothing more. It's a tool that is only meant to be a starting point which can and should be adapted to suit the needs of a project. To assert that it is somehow breaking some fundamental, unbreakable rule by adding one CSS rule to extend the functionality of Bootstrap is pretty ridiculous. That's what it's for. To customize and modify to suit your needs. And if you have a better suggestion for a way to implement a varying full width and fixed width layout on the same page, I would certainly like to hear it.

Comment: Besides, if you check the Bootstrap website closely, you will see clear [examples](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/) where containers are nested in the examples that the makers of Bootstrap created. This is [acknowledged in Bootstrap repo](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15512) and they even provide their own [solution for nesting containers](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11436) in the repo. If it's such an unbreakable rule, then why are the makers of Bootstrap doing it too?

Comment: One thing is adapting a tool for your needs and breaking principles is the other one. If you ask for a better suggestion, see my answer in this post. I'm sticking to bootstrap rules and that makes things much simpler including markup - the more elements you have in your code, the worse (performance, readability...). With the code I provided, I don't even have to add any CSS and the HTML is simpler. Never mind, I didn't mean to argue, I just wrote what bootstrap guide says: "neither container is nestable".

Comment: Tell that to the creators of Bootstrap. They are doing this too and furthermore provide a solution for nesting containers in the official Bootstrap repo. It's not about breaking some imaginary "principles". It's about using a tool to suit your needs. That is all.

Comment: I agree with @TeeJay. [Documentation clearly says](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container), that containers are not nestable. So the principle isn't imaginary.

Comment: If its a rule established by Bootstrap creators and is so fundamental that to do otherwise would be seriously detrimental, how do you explain the fact that the Bootstrap creators provided [a solution to nesting containers in the official repo](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11436)? You are building a wall around what can and cannot be done for no other reason than somebody said its only not recommended, not that its impossible. Alternatives are called for and sometimes necessary. Thats probably why the solution was provided in the bootstrap repo and is why I provided a solution here.

Comment: The reason is that some people wanted that thinking they need it.
In the official repo, the creator of Bootstrap, Mark Otto himself, says:
"... we're not going to support those nested containers. If you do wish to use them, add the negative margin as shown in this demo I put together". In other words, nesting containers is not something you need, but there's a workaround if you insist. 
I agree that alternatives are sometimes necessary, but this is not the case. Also, your solution differs from the one in the official repo suggested by Mark Otto himself but it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

I believe nesting containers is perfectly fine. As long as you remove the padding on the .container inside of .container-fluid (.container-fluid .container {padding: 0;}), then what else is not okay about it?

Comment: Actually the bootstrap docs specifically state not to do this, due to their padding.