# Multiple and/or nested Bootstrap containers?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My *understanding* is that all Bootstrap-styled elements must exist inside a `<div class="container">` element. But sometimes I see Bootstrap examples where there are multiple "containers":

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Blah, GUI stuff, blah -->
</div>

...

<div class="container">
    <!-- Blah, more GUI stuff, blah -->
</div>
```

My questions:

1. When would you ever need a single HTML page with multiple "container divs"? What benefit does this offer as opposed to just putting the entire body inside one big "container div"?
2. Would you ever want to nest "container divs" inside other ones? When/why?

Comment: If you are using a full-width carousel it has containers used for the captions so it shouldn't be in a container. Because of that you  could have a container above it and a container below it.

Comment: While @Christina is correct in that the docs say you don't nest containers, sometimes it is used and useful. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29660034/nesting-a-container-class-inside-a-container-fluid-class-in-bootstrap-3 for additional info on nesting.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

1. Some sections of the page will span the full viewport width and others won't. Some backgrounds will be the full width but the content won't.

   An example of this is a featurette area which has a background image or color that is the full width of the viewport but the content inside that, forms or whatever, don't exceed the `.container` at any given viewport width.
2. You don't nest `.container` or `.container-fluid` -- see the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container). It's not necessary.

   > Docs: Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents
   >   and house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use
   >   in your projects. Note that, due to padding and more, neither
   >   container is nestable [neither means that .container and .container-fluid are NOT to be nested].

Comment: I often have a `.container-fluid` for something like the nav bar or banner of some sort while the main site sits inside a `.container`.

Comment: @DavidG  Yes, and then you have double padding. Docs: Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in your projects. Note that, due to padding and more, neither container is nestable. http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: @DavidG. I don't use .container-fluid unless the immediate child is a .row and the columns.

Comment: Neither do I. I meant that I would have a fluid container with the nav bar so it bleeds off the edges of the screen, then after the container close tag, start a new non-fluid container with the main content.

Comment: For an example of how why you don't need to nest containers - see this example - https://stackoverflow.com/a/25742158/5551783

Comment: Big distinction to make here - maybe they shouldn't be ***directly nested***, but they can be nested, and **in some cases need to be nested**. Let's say I have a padded panel div inside the main container that is not a row or column -- in that case I need a `.container-fluid` class surrounding my rows/columns inside the panel; otherwise I would get a horizontal scrollbar (unless overflow inside the panel is set to hidden - but I might not want that, maybe I want a scrollbar if there's a lot of data inside, maybe a wide table).

Comment: In bootstrap 4 you can make nested containers - look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55297837/3655860

Comment: Is there an update for Bootstrap 4? I want to switch from fluid container to normal container on the same page.

Answer (score 17):

Unlike what some have said, you can nest a `container-fluid` inside a `container`. There is even an example on the official bootstrap website:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

Comment: In case the contents of that link eventually changes, it's version 3.3 where the example includes a `container` nesting a `container-fluid`: view-source:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/navbar/

Comment: This is a great data point! However, there's not much to gain, right? [As Patrick's answer points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55297837/114558), "most layouts do not require a nested container." In other words, if you're nesting containers, you should ask yourself if there's a simpler approach.

Comment: Update/note to self: It certainly is useful for "full width" `container` elements. However, in this case, there's a better solution: just put the `container` inside a regular old `<div>`.

Answer (score 8):

In the Layout section of the 4.3 docs, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/#containers, it now states

> While containers *can* be nested, most layouts do not require a nested container.

Just be aware of what others have stated about padding, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Actually its totally depends upon the requirement of the designer.

Some times you need full width of the row ( i mean to say viewport or a strip of visible part that you can achieved without separate container class )

http://binarytheme.com/demos?theme=bootsrap-landing-page-blue

see above template example to understand

Answer (score 2):

Save your time and switch to **Css-grid** the native CSS grid.

Bootstrap containers have a limitation,  if you look for 12 column limitation, 10-pixel padding challenge, adding to that is not native (CSS builtin) where user need to download it to his/her machine, and on top of all that the number of dive which you need to process.

With all that in mind give it a try and switch to CSS-grid
[here is a good playground to start.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp)

Now coming to the cons of CSS-grid is that still not compatible with IE.

Comment: As of Bootstrap 5, IE is not supported by it either. So less of a drawback perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

## Bootstrap 5.0+ Update

The [official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/containers/) explicetly states that:

> While containers *can* be nested, most layouts do not require a nested container.

Go on and do it if you want! :)