# Bootstrap Grid System Containers / Nesting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am finally becoming more familiar with bootstraps grid system but i'm still confused on a few things.

I know from their documentation they say containers are NOT nestable:

> Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in your projects. Note that, due to padding and more, neither container is nestable.

But what does that really mean? they appear to be nest-able to me, except that each time you nest a container there will be the extra 15px margin padding on the left and right. (just as i would expect).

When they say nestable, do they mean directly parent/child nestable?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wt69swkg/1/

I have created a fiddle of a layout I made. The layout uses a container to create the initial body structure. Then I have a div with a class *renderbody* to set background color, etc. Finally I have a div with class *renderbody-inner* with a width of 95% and margin:auto to create a centered body area with gutters of 2.5% left and right.

This leaves me with the question of should I be using a container/container-fluid inside *renderbody-inner* so that I can use col-*s?  Is the outer most container now useless because I filled it with divs that have %-based width?

^ this example is *technically* nesting containers but they are not direct parent/children. This is what is confusing me. I realize, at the end of the day I can do what I want. But I'm trying my best to follow the documentation / best practice.

```
 <div class="container">
    <div id="renderbody">
        <div id="renderbody-inner">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <!--Rendering body content here-->
              <div style="height:200px; background-color:darkgrey">

              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:
This is not a duplicate to: [Multiple and/or nested Bootstrap containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469332/multiple-and-or-nested-bootstrap-containers)

The answers to that question answer it by providing the exact quotes I provide in my question. They do not answer my question of *Why?* or provide an explanation. (Which is what I am asking)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this. A better question may be why you'd want to nest them in the first place.

The container responds to media queries with fixed widths. Everything else in Bootstrap uses percentages, which descend from this initial fixed width. When you use 2 you're going to introduce a bunch of weird effects like the padding you noticed and horizontal scrolls. You can attempt to undo these with CSS hacks but that brings us back to the question: Why do this in the first place?

I think what you might be struggling with is transitioning from typical HTML/CSS to the Grid model, which expects you to always work like this:

```
body
  container
    row
      col
        row
          col
```

And so forth, when often you'd like some intermediary non-Bootstrap tags. You can adapt to this using this class:

```
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

So that your code example can work like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="renderbody" class=box>
        <div id="renderbody-inner" class=box>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">Test</div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">Test</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/vdh8stnd/