# Bootstrap 3: Can I've a container inside a row that's inside container-fluid?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3 and knows how negative margin & padding makes the bootstrap3 grid work.

However, I'm not sure if `.container` inside a `.container-fluid > .row` is the correct way to use the grid? Will this cause responsive issues?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row"> 
    **<div class="container">**
        <div class="col-xs-6> First column</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6> Second column</div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

I know the alternate way is to put `.container` inside `col-xs-12` something like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row"> 
    **<div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="container"> **
             <div class="col-xs-6> First column</div>
             <div class="col-xs-6> Second column</div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

thanks
dk

Comment: Please see this answer, I believe that is your case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23872508/bootstrap-3-container-inside-container-fluid

Comment: In that answer, there are differing opinions and shows the alternate way, which I mentioned in my question/query, but does not quite explain as to why `.container` should / or should not be used inside `.container-fluid > .row`. I'm looking for a better, clearer explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code is wrong for a few reasons. From the [Bootstrap 3.3.x docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#overview-container)...

> "Note that, due to padding and more, neither container is nestable."

and, columns should *always* be inside directly `.row`...

> "... only columns may be immediate children of rows."

Therefore you shouldn't have col directly in container. If you want to narrow the width inside the `container-fluid` [use nesting](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-nesting), for example...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-xs-12">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6> First column</div>
                <div class="col-xs-6> Second column</div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```